# Xamarin Android In App Billing-Subscriptions GetPurchases always returns 0 products

Tags: xamarin.android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am using `Xamarin.InAppBilling` and about to get all the Purchased products through this code:

```
await Task.Run(() => { purchases = _serviceConnection.BillingHandler.GetPurchases(ItemType.Subscription).ToList(); });
```

But it always returns 0. I have 4 subscriptions In App Products on Developer Console and all of them were already purchased but when I queried them, it returns empty.

Is anyone having same problem with me? How did you fixed it? Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify if you have open connection object or not.
2. Make sure if you have created consumable products or subscriptions.

Comment: I was able to get the products in the Play Store and I have lists of products under subscriptions.